# Filtering pipe without losing full content

Tags: bash, awk, grep, sh

The title might be vague, but I have a good example:

```
echo "Test message:\nThis is a line.\nAnd this is another." | nail -s "`tail -1`" joe@localhost
```

The objective here is to send the content of the echo as the message body and using the last line as the subject. However, when I do this, I lose the body.

```
echo "Test message:\nThis is a line.\nAnd this is another." | nail joe@localhost
```

Works fine, but there is no subject.

Comment: Do you wan't the `subject line` be repeated in body or else extracted from body ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it with a named pipe, this works here:

```
mkfifo subj.fifo

echo "Test message:\nThis is a line.\nAnd this is another." |
  tee >(tail -n1 > subj.fifo) | mail -s "$(< subj.fifo)" joe@localhost

rm subj.fifo
```

Note if you use head instead of tail, you need to make `tee` ignore `SIGPIPE` signals, e.g. `trap '' PIPE`.

Comment: The `>()` redirection doesn't work in sh. In that case you could replace the `tee` bit with `pee` from moreutils, e.g. `pee "tail -n1 > subj.fifo" "cat"`. You should also replace `$(< ...)` with `$(cat ...)`.

Answer (score 2):

Since your subject appears in the last line, you must buffer all the lines (otherwise, there's no way to decide which line is the last one). It would be much easier to have the subject in the first line. Whatever. Here's a possible approach, using `mapfile` that appeared in bash 4.0:

```
printf "%s\n" "Line one in the body of message" "Line two in the body of message" "Subject in the last line" | {
    mapfile -t array
    nail -s "${array[@]: -1}" joe@localhost < <(printf "%s\n" "${array[@]:0:${#array[@]}-1}")
}
```

If you decide you want the subject in the first line, it's much much easier (just a pipe, no extraneous subshells or bufferings apart from the subject, of course):

```
printf "%s\n" "Subject in the first line" "Line one in the body of message" "Line two in the body of message"  | { read -r subject; nail -s "$subject" joe@localhost; }
```

Comment: There is no ask to suppress subjectline from body: first approach too complex, second not enough  ;-)

Comment: For what it's worth, `mapfile` is a Bash 4.x feature.

Comment: @tripleee: mentioned your comment in post.

Comment: @F.Hauri If subject needs to be included in the body, the modification is trivial (but I'm not sure that's a requirement of the OP).

Answer (score 0):

`tail` discards the lines before the last. You could use a temporary file, or put the subject first instead of last. Either way, there is no way for a pipe to both consume and keep a line, without a cooperating program a la `tee`.

```
#!/bin/sh
# use first line as subject, args are recipients
# stdin is message body
read subj
( echo "$subj"; cat ) | nail -s "$subj" "$@"
```